# Square pattern in c

Tags: c

I have to make a code to print a square made of stars(*) and its diagonals by inputing the number of lines.

For lines=5 it should look like this:[square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltwjf.png)

```
*****
*' '*
* ' *
*' '*
*****
```

what's wrong with my code?

```
This is my code so far:

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j, lines;
    printf("Enter number of lines:");
    scanf("%d",&lines);
         for(i=1; i<=lines; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=lines; j++)
        {
            if(i==1 || i==lines || j==1 || j==lines)
            {
                printf("*");
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            if(i==j)
            {
                printf(".");
            }
            if(i==(-j))
            {
                printf(".");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question, fix the linked image and explain what’s wrong with the code and what is your question.

Comment: `if ( i == (-j))` does not make sense. Both are always positive numbers.

Comment: in stackoverflow.com do not post links to temporary data.  Rather, copy/paste the data into your question

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace  '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces/  3) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  I.E.  `if( scanf("%d",&lines) != 1) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed to input number of lines\n" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are found in `stdlib.h`  Note: the `!= 1` is because there is one format specifier to be 'satisfied'

Comment: I think you forgot to tell us your question.

Comment: the posted code fails to display the diagonal line that starts at the bottom of the first column.  This is due to this statement: `if(i==(-j))`   Suggest changing that statement to: `if(i==(lines-j)`

Comment: strongly suggest modifying the code to handle each row separately.  I.E. print the first row, then in a loop print all the intervening rows, then print the last row.  In programing it is (almost) always better to break a problem into a series of very simple steps rather than trying to do everything at once

Answer (score 2):

Is your Question is you want to make a Square with a Cross inside that square? you tried it, but you didn't get what you expected?

If yes, I hope this code will help you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int n;
    printf("enter number of n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

        for (int z=0; z<=n; z++) {
            for (int y=0; y<=n; y++) {
                //printf("%d%d ", z,y);
                if (z==0 || y==0|| z==n || y==n) {
                    printf("* ");
                }
                else if (z==y || y==(n-z)) {
                    printf("' ");
                }
                else {
                    printf("  ");   
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
    }

}
```

In your code, there's some contradiction that doesn't make sense. How can if `(i ==(-j))` Applied when both of it always give a positive value?

To make it easier to understand, try to print the value of your first and second loop first. example if `n = 5`, it will give you:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05
10 11 12 13 14 15
20 21 22 23 24 25
30 31 32 33 34 35
40 41 42 43 44 45
```

and there you can see what you need to manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j, lines;
    printf("Enter number of lines:");
    scanf("%d",&lines);
        for(i=1; i<=lines; i++)
        {
            for(j=1; j<=lines; j++)
            {
                if(i==1 || i==lines || j==1 || j==lines)
                {
                    printf("*");
                }
                else if(i==j || (lines-j)+1 == i)
                {
                    printf(".");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf(" ");
                }
           }
           printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If we were to print more values of `(i,j)` we'd get an x centered on the origin with a box of stars around the 4th quadrant. We need to move the positively sloped line down a bit.